# Bumblebee Android studio Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development, android-update-app

I updated my android studio from Android studio fox to Android studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1
but none of my projects can run in **Android studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1**. I ended up getting this beautiful error.

[image: Open to view image]

Here is my gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem。
Here's how I did it:

```
//Comment the following code from settings.gradle:
/*pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}*/
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Modify the buildScript node in build.gradle in the project root directory:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Just setup Android Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 Patch 3 and used this workaround to fix gradle sync errors on a new project. mahalo.

Answer (score 14):

If your existing project gradle in kotlin (**settings.gradle.kts**), and try to import an old project as a module. You will face this issue.

Because when you try to import old project module, it will add the another **settings.gradle**(groovy).

**Solution:**

check and delete **settings.gradle** and move the ***include(":YourLib")*** to s**ettings.gradle.kts**

Answer (score 13):

If You use Android studio default configuration try change the order of the repositories. Like:
step one: go in settings.gradle file
then change like this

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

Or

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Or just try to take this in diffrent order.
Kinda funny but in many cases it has worked for me.

Comment: such a weird error! AS shouldn't have such errors atleast. +1 for you

Answer (score 12):

This happens to me with AS Bumblebee when I add a new module to my project. It adds these two lines to my project-level build.gradle in the plugins block:

```
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
```

I removed them to fix the error.

Comment: Doesn't help, the error just moves to the new module

Comment: how's this a solution? how?

Comment: Doesn't work (see this advice in https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin).

Answer (score 10):

I just clicked Toggle Offline Mode to make gradle online and started to sync project again. [See this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6dh9.png)

[image: Open to view image]

Answer (score 9):

After changing my proxy from Socks5 to HTTP the problem resolved.

You can find your proxy settings in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1081
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1081
```

Comment: I removed default setting at this file on mac os, worked fine!

Answer (score 8):

Please check your JDK version. At least your JDK version must be 11
Then restart Android studio
Check this link for more information:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#jdk-11

[image]

Comment: This actually works if you have not any firewall settings in place

Answer (score 7):

Android Gradle Plugin AGP - 7.1.0 and later versions updated some settings. You need to add repository settings in `settings.gradle` file.

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
rootProject.name = 'YourProjectName'
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#settings-gradle

Answer (score 6):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
}
```

I changed the Version to the **older Version** and the error got cleared

**Ex: '7.1.3' to '7.0.0'.**

Comment: Not resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the idea.log. this problem is caused by the network problem. Some areas cannot link to the newest gradle repository.
If you want to solve this problem, change your network which can get connect with https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I am using corporate PC with ZScaler internet security, which was blocking Android studio from downloading the plugin.

Since the Android Studio wizard created the build.gradle file, and you can easily find the com.android.application on maven repository, it was unlikely to be a declarative problem.

To fix it I exported my ZScaler certificate from Internet Options

1. Open **Internet options**
2. Go to **Trusted Root Certificate Authorities** tab
3. Select the ZScaler certificate and press the **Export** button
4. Follow the wizard and export it as DER Encoded Binary X.509.cer file

I then followed the instructions in the Android section of the following page https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trusted-store#android
to add my custom ZScaler certificate to the local JRE local keystore, by using the KeyTool program in a Powershell instance with Administrator permissions.

FYI -

- The default password for the KeyStore is **changeit**
- If you receive an error in cmd saying **access is denied** then please reopen your cmd line program with admin rights

Once finished close and reopen Android Studio and the project will hopefully sync.

Comment: I think this is the best answer and it has to be like this. Others are just temporary fixes. But one question do we have to add the Zscaler certificate of a given site like dl.google.com or google.com or maven.com ?

Comment: ok i figured it out, you have to basically add the zscaler certificates for a website from which the Android Studio is trying to download the plugin.For the above case whenever a new project is created Android Studio tries to download the plugin from https://maven.google.com/ , so we have to download the zscaler root, intermediate certificates from the browser and add it on Androdi Studio under setting> certificates oen by one and then add it to key store as explained above by @beaumondo.

Comment: Also in the Android Studio the path to keytool.exe has been change to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin ( yeah "jbr" it is , earlier it used to be jvm something )

Answer (score 1):

***New solution on 2023***

Make project Android Stuio in C, then make folder, example **C:\Users\your_pc_name\make_new_folder\your_project_name**

then click **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle** on **Gradle JDK**
change to **Embedded JDK**, then click **Apply** and **OK**, then click **Sync Try** or **Try Sync**

last click **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle** on **Gradle JDK**
change to **11** (or *version number* on Embedded JDK), then click **Apply** and **OK**, then click **Sync Try** or **Try Sync** Gradle

[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9pD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the proxy SOCKS to HTTP will fix it. The location is under Setting > System Settings > HTTP Proxy.

Answer (score 1):

My `settings.gradle` was like this and I deleted the `dependencyResolutionManagement` part then resync and the build was successful.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "customview"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the buildscript in your build.gradle (project module)

```
  buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        
        classpath 'your dependecy path'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I was trying to open a new project with a preset .gitignore and README.md files from github. AS Bumblebee gave an error also while doing the first sync. I tried couple of times with fresh install too. Same result.

I moved all files (including hidden .git folder) to temp another folder. Created new project into same folder and moved preset files/folders back.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I create a HelloWorld project. For me its a network  problem caused by settings. Because i can acess https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip or anyother sites.

before I find the problem were caused by the proxy settings in `gradle.properties`, I tried to:

- set proxy of my Android Studio(no proxy/auto-detect/manual proxy
  configuration);
- to change the order of the repositories in `settings.gradle`;
- change the version of plugins in `bulid.gradle`(7.1.2->7.0.0)
- make sure my JDK version is 11

However, none of these worked.

**How I solved:**
I solved this through delete the proxy setting in `gradle.properties`(global properties).

I don't know why they were there, I guess maybe they were added automatically during I installing my Android Studio(I set the proxy for install SDK Manager).

Answer (score 0):

change your gradle.build(Project) to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already had proxy settings in my 'gradle.properties' (global properties) file. But currently, I am not using a proxy. When I removed the lines of the proxy settings it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the specified plugin version has not been downloaded you will get a such error. Gradle downloads it the next time you build your project or click: **File > Sync Project with Gradle Files** from the Android Studio menu bar.
After this, your project will successfully build :)

For more information refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#jdk-11).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who still has this problem, the solution in my case was **my laptop being offline**. Connecting to a network and syncing project with Gradle files (tiny elephant icon in top right corner) solved it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Before that, you must download gradle version *gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip* "from:- [link gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)" and install it on your device, [default gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVjOd.png) and then we choose it as in the second image *specified location*
[specified location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT8Fi.png)
Then click on Project Structure and choose.
[choose proje.struc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyIhZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

After run `./gradlew assembleDebug --debug`, I find out it's because I have invalid httpProxy-setting in the file ~/.gradle/`gradle.properties`.

And I remove all httpProxy-setting in the global `gradle.properties`, and then the problem is solved.

So I suggest you can check your global and project's `gradle.properties` and remove possible invalid httpProxy-setting and retry.

Answer (score 0):

To resolving this problem we have to change the jdk to upper version. we should use the last version.

It resolved my problem.
I hope to helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, I got stuck for more than 2 days and only deleting the proxies and letting android studio regenerate them solved my issue.

In the file gradle.properties(Global Properties) delete the lines

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

Or whatever is in there, and let android studio resolve that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the setting.gradle. Paste this.

```
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    rootProject.name = "this_must_be_project_root_folder_name"
    include ':app'
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change it to an older version and it should work

Answer (score -3):

delete init.d from .gradle (hidden directory)

Answer (score -3):

I solved by close Charles,and delete net setting like this:
[image: result]