# New project fails building in Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 patch 1

Tags: android, android-studio, build

When I create a new project (with the default settings, wasn't modified) in the newest Android Studio version (no more updates available) I get this message:

> Build file
> 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle'
> line: 3
>
> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.1', apply: false]
> was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> ...
>
> Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.2.1')
>
> Searched in the following repositories:
> Gradle Central Plugin Repository
> Google
> MavenRepo
> at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
> at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)

While I can open projects that were created with an older version just fine.

### This is the default project structure:

---

**`build.gradle:`**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**`app/build.gradle:`**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**`settings.gradle:`**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

[image]

---

I tried to lower the APG and Gradle versions, reinstall Android Studio, reset to default settings, but it still fails.
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Check your settings.gradle. Now repository downloads are moved to there

Comment: @GobuCSG see update

Comment: Gradle 7 and above Java 11 required. If not download and install it then restart your studio.

Comment: @GobuCSG I'm using java 11 and the gradle is 7.3.3 as you can see

Comment: I think it's known issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/228336564

Try this 
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

Comment: @ATP let's try this `File`>`Sync Project with Gradle Files`. Make sure that your grade toggle is online mode see this image https://img-bc.icode.best/f584bfba8109455d9f583e01ed15ba62.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with the internet supply which blocked the access to the `google()` repository.
Using hotspot solved the problem.

Comment: wow, this is awful. I'm glad you could figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

The message means that you are defining a dependency that can not be found in any of the repositories that are defined in `settings.gradle`. This file can be found in your project root folder.

Maybe your gradle cache is having problems. Try to invalidate all caches in Android Studio and restart it: File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Doesn't work, As I said, I also reinstalled android studio and it doesn't work.

Comment: could you list the "sources" that is listed below the message please?

Comment: Here are some ideas to the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947176/bumblebee-android-studio-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-0

Comment: Tried them all, still doesn't work. It seems to be a bug. I opened an issue on issuetracker waiting for their response.

Answer (score 0):

Check following things:
in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

In android studio preferences `Build,Execut....>Build Tools>Gradle` Set `Use Gradle from gradle-wrapper.properties file` and `Gradle JDK` to `11`