# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

When I create a new project in Android Studio(java). This Error comes out, How to solve?

```
build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\sambit.pradhan\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.2.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v5rb.png)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70947176/16177121) you're looking for