# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, plugins

Why this problem is appearing I can't understand, when ever I am creating a new project always I get this type of error, can anyone help me to find out the solution

here what problem I am getting,

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
* Exception is:
```

org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

```
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
```

- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google
  MavenRepo
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)

Comment: I also encountered this error today.
Try change the order of the repositories -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635083/7213689)
and If you are in Iran, you must use VPN or DNS(Like www.shecan.ir) due to sanctions

Comment: Did you find a solution yet @Aisha Kumari?

Answer (score -1):

Check this string exist in Project build.gradle[image]