# (KotlinSourceSet with name 'androidMain' not found.) How can I add android as a build target to a Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add `android()` as a build target to a Kotlin Multiplatform library so that I can add a specific library for the android target. All the other targets (jvm, linux, ios) work fine, but android seems to have issues, because the KotlinSourceSet is not being create like the others.

That's where I get the error:

> KotlinSourceSet with name 'androidMain' not found.

I wonder, do I have to add the SourceSet manually? Am I missing some crucial build step?

Here is my `gradle.build.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.0"

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
    }
}

group = "zzz.xxxx"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    linuxX64("linux")
    ios()
    android()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("...")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test")) 
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("...")
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation ("...")
            }
        }

        val jvmTest by getting

    }
}
```

I tried adding a androidMain folder, but it is not getting recognized as a KotlinSourceSet. Non of the resources online seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add android as a build target your need to setup [android-gradle-plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#kts) first.

With example setting of android plugin `gradle.build.kts` will be:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.0"
    id("com.android.library") version "7.3.0" // (1) add plugin
}

//...

// (2) setup plugin
android {
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Before you are adding Android Gradle plugin:

- Check that Google Maven repository is listed in your `settings.gradle(.kts)` file
- Check the Android Gradle plugin is added to the project `build.gradle(.kts)` file
- Check the Android Gradle plugin is [compatible with your Gradle version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think this is the solution. However if i try to do this, i get: `Plugin [id: 'com.android.library', version: '7.3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

Comment: I've never come across this error, maybe some advices from here will work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947176/bumblebee-android-studio-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-0

Comment: @rolator I've added update based on what I found about your new issue. Tell me if it helps