# (KotlinSourceSet with name 'iosMain' not found.) How can I add android as a build target to a Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

There is such a topic on the website stackoverflow.com:
[KotlinSourceSet with name 'androidMain' not found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75314123/kotlinsourceset-with-name-androidmain-not-found-how-can-i-add-android-as-a%5D).

I have a similar problem: "KotlinSourceSet with name 'iosMain' not found."

I don't quite understand how to resolve it. Help me please.
[![Task 1][1]][1]
[![Task 2][2]][2]

Update: resolved, now I got:
Built iOS application: failed with code 65 ...
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Drop your build.gradle.kts of shared module, settings.gradle.kts, etc configuration files here to know more.

Comment: @Harsh Panchal here ->
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J4_4RQvCn3Sz1K-NBRgGEC0c4y2Ld47k?usp=drive_link

Comment: please let us know how you look at it

Comment: Here is a link to prefer: https://medium.com/icerock/enable-iosmain-sourceset-in-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-projects-91168db9ac5c

Comment: @HarshPanchal did you manage to see the code I shared?

Comment: Here is one of my KMP project's build.gradle.kts file of shared module: https://github.com/HarshPanchal18/Counter-KMP/blob/main/shared/build.gradle.kts try cross checking with yours.

Comment: @HarshPanchal ok, thanks. but now I'm getting this:
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/vasiliikarpenko/AndroidStudioProjects/ViPlanApp-master/shared/build.gradle.kts' line: 66

* What went wrong:
KotlinSourceSet with name 'iosMain' not found.

Comment: so: KotlinSourceSet with name 'iosMain' not found.

Comment: And I don't understand what can I do with that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic `ios` sourceset has been deprecated and you now have to specify the targets more explicitly. This means that for the adding of targets instead of adding a generic `ios()`, you specify the separate targets:

```
kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    // ios() // -> This has been deprecated
    iosArm64()
    iosX64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()
```

And when specifying the sourcesets, you add their `main`/`test` targets:

```
sourceSets {
...
val iosArm64Main by getting {
    dependencies {
      ...
    }
}
val iosArm64Test by getting {
    dependencies {
      ...
    }
}
val iosX64Main by getting {
    dependencies {
      ...
    }
}
val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting {
    dependencies {
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. And the below code worked for me. `baseName` can be any string.

```
  listOf(
    iosX64(),
    iosArm64(),
    iosSimulatorArm64()
  ).forEach { iosTarget ->
    iosTarget.binaries.framework {
      baseName = "ComposeApp"
      isStatic = true
    }
  }

 sourceSets {
    val iosX64Main by getting
    val iosArm64Main by getting
    val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
    val iosMain by creating {
      dependsOn(commonMain.get())
      iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
      iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
      iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
    }
  }
```