# How can I solve this problem? Plugin error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

My error when build firstapp in Kotlin:

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '11.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: try adding more details like your build.gradle and the whole error that is shown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947176/bumblebee-android-studio-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Check version compatibility with Gradle

try: clean your project and rebuilt your project