Flutter run - Build failed with an exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file '/Users/fm-pc-lt-144/Desktop/Flutter/Flutter Projects/new_project/android/settings.gradle' line: 22

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:



Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
Searched in the following repositories:
Google
MavenRepo
Gradle Central Plugin Repository


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

*build.gradle
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
 }

 rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
 subprojects {
 project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
 subprojects {
 project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
 }

 tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }

*build.gradle
 plugins {
   id "com.android.application"
   id "kotlin-android"
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
  }

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if    (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
  }
}

def flutterVersionCode = l. 
localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
   if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
     flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = 
localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
 if (flutterVersionName == null) {
   flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
 namespace "com.example.new_project"
 compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
 ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.new_project"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
}

flutter {
   source '../..'
}
dependencies {}

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) 
}
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in 
local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}
settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()
includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")


repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}  
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
 }
include ":app"


If you are using Android Studio, take a look at the answer mentioning the proxy on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947176/bumblebee-android-studio-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-0 It solved my problem

I am using Visual Studio.

please give both build.gradle and settings.gradle files

Hi Malak, It's done.
